# Как сделать бекап mysql, если на диске нет места

Tags: vps

На сервере VPS есть база mysql весом 90ГБ, как сделать бекап, если на диске осталось 10ГБ свободного места? Можно ли как то сделать бекап на другой сервер? (есть в наличии).

Comment: У вас должен быть доступ, можно конечно. За это отвечает опция `distination`. Так же можете делать не полную копию базы, или сжать ее.

Comment: *Можно ли как то сделать бекап на другой сервер?* Просто сервер или MySQL-сервер? Можно ли временно остановить MySQL сервер-источник? *база mysql весом 90ГБ* Каков объём ДАННЫХ, подлежащих резервированию? за вычетом индексов, таблиц-справочников и "пустого" места в файлах таблиц.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqldump your-db |ssh -C login@drugoi.server "cat >/path/to/backup.sql"`